# How can an Interpolator be used with an animation in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have the following code:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "barHeight", maxInPx).setDuration(1000).start();
```

I would like to add an `Interpolator` to the `ObjectAnimator`; however, I receive an error stating, "Can not call start() on primitive type void" when I use the following code:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "barHeight", maxInPx).setDuration(1000).setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator()).start();
```

How can I use an `Interpolator` with an `ObjectAnimator`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because `setInterpolator()` does not return the `ObjectAnimator` instance. You will have to break up the code:

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "barHeight", maxInPx);
objectAnimator.setDuration(1000);
objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
objectAnimator.start();
```

You could shorten it a little bit with the following code but that's about as much of a code reduction as you'll get.

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "barHeight", maxInPx).setDuration(1000);
objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
objectAnimator.start();
```